# Batch print .pdf files from list.txt file

Tags: batch-file, pdf

The batch file will be in the same folder with pdflist.txt and .pdf files!

Here is what i want:

In "pdflist.txt" will be file names (not full name) that looks like:

```
204820

202381
```

I want to print all files that match text from pdflist.txt

so in my case these files will be printed in adobe acrobat:

```
598213-M204820.pdf

591111-M202381.pdf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For printing directly form you'll need additional script. You can check [robvanderwoude's collection](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/printfiles.php).Here I'll be using [**printjs.bat**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/printJS.bat):

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%# in ("pdflist.txt") do (
    for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%А in ('dir /b *%%#*pdf') do (
        call printjs.bat "%%~fА"
    )
)
```

the default printer will be used.